# Threads run method

Tags: java

Can we use directly run method as done in the below class. It is producing the same result
as that when we use t1.start();. Is there any reason behind using only start method for invoking run?

```
public class runcheck extends Thread{

    public void run(){

        System.out.println(" i am run");

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        runcheck as = new runcheck();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(as);
        t1.run();

    }

}
```

Comment: Current practice says that `runcheck` shouldn't extend `Thread`, but merely implement `Runnable`. (Mostly for separation of concerns - you usually have no business overriding the other `Thread` methods.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it will run in the same thread. It's equivalent to calling a method on a normal object.

`start()` is what you want. It calls a `native` method that actually spawns an OS `Thread` to execute the `run()` code in.

Comment: Yes, run is there just to tell the Thread object where to start execution for this thread. By calling "run" you're literally just calling a method. Implementing Runnable(or extending Thread), doesn't give the method any magic power.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article1131.html):

`start()` calls `run()` asynchronously (non-blocking)

while calling `run()` directly results in synchronous calling (blocking)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can invoked `run` directly from `main` method, in this case the `main` method and `run` method runs one after the other.

Order

`main -> t.run() -> main` - Only 1 Thread

But if you call `start` method on the instance `t1`, then the `run` method and the `main` method runs parallely.

`main -> t.start() -> main` - 1st Thread

`run()` - 2nd Thread.